# Using startActivityForResult to Add Data To List

Tags: java, android, listview, startactivityforresult

I'm new to Android. I want to create a directory in my app. I will only display names there. I'm using Directory class to display names and AddPerson class to add there. However AddPerson is not working. Here is my Directory:

```
        package com.example.user.myapplication;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;
        import android.widget.ListView;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class Directory extends AppCompatActivity {
            ArrayList<String> personList = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                ListView list;
                ImageButton addButton;
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory);
                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, personList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                addButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
                addButton.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.user.myapplication.AddPerson");
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                            }
                        }

                );

            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if ( requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
                    String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                    personList.add(result);
                }
            }

        }
```

This is the AddPerson class:
    package com.example.user.myapplication;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class AddPerson extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button addButton;
        EditText nameText;
        Directory d = new Directory();
        public String name;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_person);
            addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            addButton.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                            EditText mailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                            name = nameText.getText().toString();
                            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                            returnIntent.putExtra("result", name);
                            setResult(1, returnIntent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }

            );

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if is always false because you are returning 1 as the `resultCode`:

`if ( requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK )`

You need to return the correct result code with `setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);`

On top of that, each time you modify your dataset you need to notify the ListView's adapter that it has changed. Move your adapter to a class variable and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding the resulting person.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through and seeing what happens when returning from the second activity?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: Debugging your app and setting a breakpoint in the `onActivityResult`. However, I see another issue with your code. You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after modifying your ArrayList.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main thing that sticks out is that you're not using RESULT_OK (or RESULT_CANCELED), maybe try:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                            nameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                            EditText mailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                            name = nameText.getText().toString();
                            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                            returnIntent.putExtra("result", name);
                            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                            finish();
```

Also, why are you manually creating a Directory (which is an Activity in this context) object in your AddPerson Activity?  The system is the only thing that should create Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);`

remember that

> int RESULT_OK has a value of Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)

then you will have no problems to add data to the list:

```
  @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                   
                if ( requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ){
                    String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                    personList.add(result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried it but still problem continues. Thank you anyway